# How to find words followed by space and replace with tag?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some string values in the array

```
var anchors = [
        "Can", 
        ", please?"
    ];
```

I have string like the below example

```
<anchor>0</anchor> you repeat that<anchor>1</anchor>
```

I want to frame the resulting string in the below

```
Can <drop></drop> <drop></drop> <drop></drop>, please?

I want to replace all the <anchor>0</anchor> to the words in the given array and words into <drop></drop> tag
```

Someone please help me to frame the resulting string using javascript string operations or regex

Comment: Where's that extra `drop` coming from? And what happened with the space after the comma? "all the 0"?? Sloppy work and programming are archenemies.

Comment: What??????  No clue what you're trying to ask.

Comment: I edited the question and added description about it

Comment: what about comma?? how they disappear??

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV Which comma you are talking about? Everything in place

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I modified the question. Can you check it now?

Comment: you are saying you want to replace the space in your string with some tag . and in your string contain some comma then what about that ?? also you are given an array not a string and it is also incorrect , var anchors = [
        "Can", 
        ", please?"
    ];
it is incorrect format

Comment: @Jamen I added description to the question. Sorry for the inconvenience. Can you check it now?

Comment: please provide the correct string and with what delimiter or word you want to replace

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV I modified the question. Can you check it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80454/discussion-between-arunprasanth-kv-and-sathya-venkat).

Comment: What constitutes a word?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Which word you are asking about?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like below

```
var myarray =[ "Can",",please?" ];
var inputstring ="<anchor>0</anchor> you repeat that <anchor>1</anchor>"
var len=inputstring.split(" ").length-1
var inputstring1;
for(var i=0;i<=myarray.length;i++)
{
inputstring1 +=   inputstring.replace("<anchor>"+i+"</anchor>",myarray[i]) 
}

var inputstring2=inputstring
for(var i=0;i<=myarray.length;i++)
{
inputstring2 =   inputstring2.replace("<anchor>"+i+"</anchor>","") 
}
myarrayremovedelemets=inputstring2.split(" ")
myarrayremovedelemets.push.apply(myarrayremovedelemets, myarray);

alert(myarrayremovedelemets);
```

then replace inputstring1 with `<drop></drop>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following logic with [`callback function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

**Output:**

```
Can <drop></drop> <drop></drop> <drop></drop>, please?
```

**Code:**

```js
var anchors = [
    "Can", 
    ", please?"
];
var replaceCallback = function(match, g1, g2) { 
if(g1 != null) return anchors[g1];
if(g2 != null) return "<drop></drop>";
return match;
}
var str = "<anchor>0</anchor> you repeat that<anchor>1</anchor>";

str = str.replace(/<anchor>(\d+)<\/anchor>|(\w+)/g, replaceCallback); 

alert(str);
```

**Edit:** Updated regex:

```
/<anchor>(\d+)<\/anchor>|((?:(?!<anchor>)\S)+)/g
```

**Edit:** For `single`:

```
/<(?:anchor|single)>(\d+)<\/(?:anchor|single)>|((?:(?!<(?:anchor|single)>)\S)+)/g
```

Comment: I am facing problem with the following string 
Excuse <anchor>0</anchor> where is Barkley’s <anchor>1</anchor>

Barkley's is parsed into two drops

Comment: It is working fine, is it possible to add one more filter in the word <single> in addition to <anchor>

Comment: It works great!! I changed in few areas to work based on my needs. Thank you so much!!